# MySQL: insert data in tables with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

In MySQL, I have got three tables: `projects`, `tags` and `tags_posts`.

`tags_posts` is a table between `projects` and `tags` that holds the `project_id` and the `tag_id` as foreign keys. This, so I am able to easily select all of the tags for `project_id = x`, or to select all projects for `tag_id = y`.

Of course, I want to add projects to the database. I have learnt of `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;` so that the queries will be executed altogether, or not at all. 
But what query do I have to use to `INSERT`, `SELECT` and `UPDATE` data to those three tables at once?

I have thought about using:
`INSERT INTO projects([column-1], [column-2], [column-N]) VALUES([value-1], [value-2], [value-N]);`

`INSERT INTO tags_posts(tag_id, project_id) VALUES(1, LAST_INSERT_ID());`

`INSERT INTO tags(tag_id, tag_name) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'php');`

MySQL Workbench gives an error 1452: a foreign key constraint fails. PHPMyAdmin hangs on executing this query.
Who can help me on using the right queries to `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `SELECT` for these three tables?
[image: ER Diagram of the three tables mentioned]

Comment: You must insert into `tags_posts` LAST, after the rows have been inserted into `tags` and `projects`.

Comment: Of course, that sounds reasonable! But, besides that, are my queries valid?

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert parent (`projects` and `tags`) rows first and then add references to the many-to-many table `tags_posts`.

Your code might look like this

```
START TRANSACTION;
-- Add a project
INSERT INTO projects(title, description, datum) VALUES ('title1', 'description1', CURDATE());
SET @project_id  = LAST_INSERT_ID();
-- Add a tag 
INSERT INTO tags (tag_name) VALUES ('tag1');
SET @tag_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
-- Now add a tag to the project
INSERT INTO tags_posts (tag_id, project_id) VALUES (@tag_id, @project_id);
COMMIT;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5e89/1)** demo

---

If you need to add a tag and then add several projects with this tag you can do

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tags (tag_name) VALUES ('tag1');
SET @tag_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO projects(title, description, datum) VALUES ('title1', 'description1', CURDATE());
INSERT INTO tags_posts (tag_id, project_id) VALUES (@tag_id, LAST_INSERT_ID());

INSERT INTO projects(title, description, datum) VALUES ('title2', 'description2', CURDATE());
INSERT INTO tags_posts (tag_id, project_id) VALUES (@tag_id, LAST_INSERT_ID());
COMMIT;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef68b/1)** demo